# aiohttp failed response.json() with status 500

Tags: python, json, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Server proxies requests.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def send_async_request(method, url, data, timeout):
    with ClientSession() as session:
        response = yield from asyncio.wait_for(
            session.request(method, url, data=data), timeout=timeout
        )
        return response
```

Everything works on the response codes 200.
When it comes to 500 response code can not read the json from the response.
Exception ServerDisconnectedError:

```
response = yield from send_async_request(request.method, url)
response_json = yield from response.json()

Traceback (most recent call last):  

File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\server.py", line 285, in start
    yield from self.handle_request(message, payload)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web.py", line 90, in handle_request
    resp = yield from handler(request)
  File "D:/projects/SeleniumGridDispatcher/trunk/application.py", line 122, in proxy_wd
    response_json = yield from response.json()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 764, in json
    yield from self.read()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client_reqrep.py", line 720, in read
    self._content = yield from self.content.read()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 486, in wrapper
    result = yield from func(self, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 541, in read
    return (yield from super().read(n))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 261, in read
    block = yield from self.readany()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 486, in wrapper
    result = yield from func(self, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 549, in readany
    return (yield from super().readany())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\streams.py", line 284, in readany
    yield from self._waiter
  File "C:\Python34\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 358, in __iter__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
  File "C:\Python34\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 290, in _wakeup
    future.result()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
aiohttp.errors.ServerDisconnectedError
```

Help to understand what was going on.
Python: 3.4.4
aiohttp: 0.22.5

Comment: http client does not read the full body of the request, did not resolve

Answer (score 0):

500 errors may occur at any time especially if the server is under high load or unstable. Make your code more resilient by catching the exception. Then you might retry or just return the response.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def send_async_request(method, url, data, timeout):
    with ClientSession() as session:
        try:             
            response = yield from asyncio.wait_for(
                session.request(method, url, data=data), timeout=timeout
            )
        except  Exception as e:
            print("%s has error '%s: %s'" % (url, response.status, response.reason))
            # now you can decide what you want to do
            # either return the response anyways or do some handling right here
        return response
```

Comment: 500 returns a different server and this is a normal behavior of his, I just need to traverse this body 500 further through my server, and I can not get the body falls on response.json(). The request itself runs smoothly.

Comment: That's the point - the message probably has no body. Catch the exception as I wrote you (or catch it in the lower part of your code - not sure if it matters), then abort the json conversion or however the error handling should look like.

Comment: I look through the local proxy traffic, body there

HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
Date: Tue, 30 Aug 2016 14:13:45 GMT
Server: Jetty/5.1.x (Windows 7/6.1 amd64 java/1.8.0_101
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 7408
Connection: close

{"sessionId": ....}

Comment: Ah ok, now I see your point. Nevertheless, you have to catch the exception, it is what makes your code crash. Have you tried my initial code snippet? It could actually work for what you want to achieve.

Comment: I can put a breakpoint and debug, but here's what to look for so. It falls on this line response_json = yield from response.json(), I need to check to check it? 
The answer came, I can not out of it just to get the body, headers, and the statute is.

Comment: I know where your code fails. But please answer my question: *Did you try my code snippet?*

Comment: Yes, I tried, but nothing has changed since falls elsewhere

Comment: Ok, so my approach did not fix it, therefore the question. It is not working because of the yield otherwise the fix would work perfectly. Try to catch the exception in the lower part of your code and see if that  works:
try:
    response = yield from send_async_request(request.method, url)
    response_json = yield from response.json()
except  Exception as e:
...

Comment: I do not quite understand how I can help handling Exception, but well made, with the exception falls, too, to get the request body could not: ServerDisconnectedError()

Answer (score 0):

Please check `Content-Length` for 500 response.
Looks like aiohttp tries to read json body but the body is shorter than specified in headers.

Comment: >>> response.headers.get('CONTENT-LENGTH')
'7217'
How to check that it is in this matter?

Comment: Make sure response has exactly 7217 bytes in body.
Otherwise you have malicious server.
You may read response by `.content.read_any()` though.

Comment: It differs from the response.headers.get('CONTENT-LENGTH'). But to see the proxy full body request and readany() returns only part of the. Response example [link](https://inside.tensor.ru/shared/disk/f687962c-eecb-4e88-9d49-bec6f082b20b)

Comment: No guaranties for malformed responses, sorry

Comment: Unfortunately the server that returns the requests and improve our we can not. In the body of the request may come as any text, there is a way to get all the correct body of the request? I would not want to use a third-party library for sending requests.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you